# What is the best way to deal with DOM attributes from other modules with MarionetteJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

Now I am using Backbone.Marionette a lot and I have some concerns about what is the best way to deal with DOM external attributes.

Sometimes I need to do something like this:

**my-view.js**

```
var MyView = ItemView.extend(
//...
//insert a lot of code here
//...
myFunction: function() {
    var someKindOfCalculation = this.$('.my-field').height() + Backbone.$('.my-external-module').height();
     //...
}
```

Where `.my-external-module`is a DOM element which is inside of another MarionetteJS module.
My current way to solve this is something like:

**my-view.js**

```
//Some way to obtain the App.events variable(browserify, requireJS, global...)
//...
var MyView = ItemView.extend(
//...
//insert a lot of code here
//...
myFunction: function() {
    App.events.on('app:MyOtherModule:height:returned', function(heightForModule) {
        var someKindOfCalculation = this.$('.my-field').height() + heightForModule;
        //...
    });
    App.events.trigger('app:MyOtherModule:height');
}
```

**my-other-module.js**

```
//Some way to obtain the App.events variable(browserify, requireJS, global...)
//...
var MyOtherModule = Controller.extend({
    //...
    //insert a lot of code here
    //...
    start: function() {
        App.Events.on('app:MyOtherModule:height', function() {
            App.Events.trigger('app:MyOtherModule:height:returned', this.view.$el.height());
        });
    }    
})
```

Although it works fine, this way to obtain 'external' DOM attributes is so weird for me, because we are including a new callback every time that you want to get an external attribute.
Are you using another way to get DOM attributes when these DOM elements are outside of our current module/view ? Is this way to get data valid for you?

Comment: Though you shouldn't be asking _that_ much about DOM properties, [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) will make your life easier.

Comment: if i were you i would use Request Response to communicate between modules and view methods to provide data from view, but don't really  understand requesting DOM infomation

Comment: In my particular case, I have a special case of module where I have to do some calculations using height and width from another modules in a execution time (Obviously, to do html & css layouts/changes is not enough for my case). Well, I think to use a Request Response with Backbone.Radio could be the best way to do this. I would accept a complete example about how to use it in this case as a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Marionette ships with Backone.Wreqr, but the differences between Wreqr and Radio, for the consumer, are only semantic. I'll show you how to set up and consume a Request Response handler with both.

With a Request Response handler you don't have to ensure that **my-view.js** has been created, because **my-view.js** will actively request the data, rather than wait for **my-other-module.js** to publish it.

## Backbone.Wreqr

Using the views you shared in your post, you'd first want to set up a Request Response handler in **my-other-module.js**. Instead triggering an event in a controller, we'll set up a Request Response handler in the **my-other-module.js** view, which we'll call **my-other-view.js**.

### Setting up the handler

First you have to enable the request messaging system, much like you use `App.events`. So in some centralized part of your app (like a main controller for example), you'd execute:

```
App.reqres = new Backbone.Wreqr.RequestResponse();
```

#### my-other-view.js

```
var MyOtherView = ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.setupHandlers();
  },

  setupHandlers: function() {
    App.reqres.setHandler('app:MyOtherModule:height', function(){
      return this.view.$el.height();
    });
  }
});
```

### Request the data

And on **my-view.js** you'd simply pass the `App` reference in an get a hold of `App.reqres` and invoke the request. Like this:

#### my-view.js

```
var MyView = ItemView.extend{(
  //...
  //insert a lot of code here
  //...
  myFunction: function() {
    var heightForModule= App.reqres.request('app:MyOtherModule:height');
    var someKindOfCalculation = this.$('.my-field').height() + heightForModule;                 
  }
});
```

And that's it! This certainly saves a lot of code.

#### Backbone.Radio

Radio is an optimized (and smaller) version of Wreqr that preserves its functionality. To use it we simply adopt the language that API, but the usage is essentially identical.

First we set up our request messaging bus, in a central place on our app,

_.extend(App.reqres, Backbone.Radio.Requests);

And then we simply change the method names

#### my-other-view.js

```
var MyOtherView = ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.setupHandlers();
  },

  setupHandlers: function() {
    App.reqres.reply('app:MyOtherModule:height', function(){
      return this.view.$el.height();
    });
  }
});
```

#### my-view.js

```
var MyView = ItemView.extend{(
  //...
  //insert a lot of code here
  //...
  myFunction: function() {
    var heightForModule= App.reqres.request('app:MyOtherModule:height');
    var someKindOfCalculation = this.$('.my-field').height() + heightForModule;                 
  }
});
```

## Final word

Both Wreqr and Radio use channels. With channels you can create dedicated messaging buses that keep your messages separate. Take a look here: [Backbone.Radio Channels](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio#channel).

Comment: Thank you for your concise response!